# MySQL was stopped

Tags: mysql

My MySQL server was stopped this morning when I turned on my PC. When I restarted it, I received the following error:

```
Jun 21 04:25:31 container systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has begun starting up. 

Jun 21 04:25:31 container audit[2697]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open"
profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/2697/status" pid=2697
comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=112 ouid=112

Jun 21 04:25:31 container audit[2697]: AVC apparmor="DENIED"
operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld"
name="/sys/devices/system/node/" pid=2697 comm="mysqld"
requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=112 ouid=0 

Jun 21 04:25:31 container audit[2697]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open"
profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/2697/status" pid=2697
comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=112 ouid=112

Jun 21 04:25:31 container kernel: audit: type=1400
audit(1529555131.547:18): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open"
profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/2697/status" pid=2697
comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied 

Jun 21 04:25:31 container
kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1529555131.547:19): apparmor="DENIED"
operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld"
name="/sys/devices/system/node/" pid=2697 comm="mysqld"
requested_mask="r 

Jun 21 04:25:31 container kernel: audit: type=1400
audit(1529555131.547:20): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open"
profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/2697/status" pid=2697
comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied 

Jun 21 04:25:31 container
audit[2697]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod"
profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld"
name="/data1/database/mysql/container.lower-test" pid=2697
comm="mysqld" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c 

Jun 21 04:25:31
container audit[2697]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod"
profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld"
name="/data1/database/mysql/container.lower-test" pid=2697
comm="mysqld" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c 

Jun 21 04:25:31
container audit[2697]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod"
profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld"
name="/data1/database/mysql/container.lower-test" pid=2697
comm="mysqld" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c 

Jun 21 04:25:31
container kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1529555131.703:21):
apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld"
name="/data1/database/mysql/container.lower-test" pid=2697
comm="mysqld" 

Jun 21 04:25:31 container kernel: audit: type=1400
audit(1529555131.703:22): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod"
profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld"
name="/data1/database/mysql/container.lower-test" pid=2697
comm="mysqld" Jun 21 04:25:31 container kernel: audit: type=1400
audit(1529555131.703:23): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod"
profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld"
name="/data1/database/mysql/container.lower-test" pid=2697
comm="mysqld" 

Jun 21 04:25:31 container audit[2697]: AVC
apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld"
name="/data1/database/mysql/ibdata1" pid=2697 comm="mysqld"
requested_mask="wr" denied_mask="wr" fsuid=112  

Jun 21 04:25:31
container kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1529555131.727:24):
apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld"
name="/data1/database/mysql/ibdata1" pid=2697 comm="mysqld"
requested_mas 

Jun 21 04:25:32 container systemd[1]: mysql.service:
Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE 

Jun 21 04:26:01
container systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed. 

Jun 21 04:26:01 container systemd[1]: mysql.service: Unit entered failed state. 

Jun 21 04:26:01 container
systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'. Jun 21
04:26:01 container systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time
over, scheduling restart. 

Jun 21 04:26:01 container systemd[1]:
Stopped MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has finished shutting down. Jun 21 04:26:01 container systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has begun starting up. 

Jun 21 04:26:01 container kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1529555161.799:25): apparmor="DENIED"
operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/2787/status"
pid=2787 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied 

Jun 21 04:26:01
container kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1529555161.799:26):
apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld"
name="/sys/devices/system/node/" pid=2787 comm="mysqld"
requested_mask="r 

Jun 21 04:26:01 container kernel: audit: type=1400
audit(1529555161.799:27): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open"
profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/2787/status" pid=2787
comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied 

Jun 21 04:26:01 container
audit[2787]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open"
profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/2787/status" pid=2787
comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=112 ouid=112

Jun 21 04:26:01 container audit[2787]: AVC apparmor="DENIED"
operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld"
name="/sys/devices/system/node/" pid=2787 comm="mysqld"
requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=112 ouid=0 

Jun 21 04:26:01
container audit[2787]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open"
profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/2787/status" pid=2787
comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=112 ouid=112

Jun 21 04:26:01 container audit[2787]: AVC apparmor="DENIED"
operation="mknod" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld"
name="/data1/database/mysql/container.lower-test" pid=2787
comm="mysqld" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c 

Jun 21 04:26:01
container audit[2787]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod"
profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld"
name="/data1/database/mysql/container.lower-test" pid=2787
comm="mysqld" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c 

Jun 21 04:26:01
container audit[2787]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod"
profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld"
name="/data1/database/mysql/container.lower-test" pid=2787
comm="mysqld" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c 

Jun 21 04:26:01
container kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1529555161.955:28):
apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld"
name="/data1/database/mysql/container.lower-test" pid=2787
comm="mysqld" 

Jun 21 04:26:01 container kernel: audit: type=1400
audit(1529555161.955:29): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod"
profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld"
name="/data1/database/mysql/container.lower-test" pid=2787
comm="mysqld" 

Jun 21 04:26:01 container kernel: audit: type=1400
audit(1529555161.955:30): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod"
profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld"
name="/data1/database/mysql/container.lower-test" pid=2787
comm="mysqld" 

Jun 21 04:26:01 container audit[2787]: AVC
apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld"
name="/data1/database/mysql/ibdata1" pid=2787 comm="mysqld"
requested_mask="wr" denied_mask="wr" fsuid=112  

Jun 21 04:26:01
container kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1529555161.979:31):
apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld"
name="/data1/database/mysql/ibdata1" pid=2787 comm="mysqld"
requested_mas 

Jun 21 04:26:02 container systemd[1]: mysql.service:
Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
```

I already removed `ib_logfile0` and `ib_logfile1`. And I changed the permission to `777` for the directory `ibdata1`. But no luck.

### Output of error.log

```
tail -30 /var/log/mysql/error.log

2018-06-21T05:42:14.142533Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
2018-06-21T05:42:43.804474Z 0 [Warning] Changed limits: max_open_files: 1024 (requested 5000) 
2018-06-21T05:42:43.804512Z 0 [Warning] Changed limits: table_open_cache: 431 (requested 2000)
2018-06-21T05:42:43.956157Z 0 [Warning] Can't create test file /data1/database/mysql/container.lower-test 
2018-06-21T05:42:43.956199Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.21-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) starting as process 16392 ... 
2018-06-21T05:42:43.958950Z 0 [Warning] Can't create test file /data1/database/mysql/container.lower-test
2018-06-21T05:42:43.958974Z 0 [Warning] Can't create test file /data1/database/mysql/container.lower-test 
2018-06-21T05:42:43.961483Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2018-06-21T05:42:43.961499Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins 
2018-06-21T05:42:43.961505Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes 
2018-06-21T05:42:43.961509Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2018-06-21T05:42:43.961513Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8 
2018-06-21T05:42:43.961517Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO 
2018-06-21T05:42:43.961740Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1 
2018-06-21T05:42:43.961844Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions 
2018-06-21T05:42:43.963259Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2018-06-21T05:42:43.970400Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool 
2018-06-21T05:42:43.972394Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2018-06-21T05:42:43.982544Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The innodb_system data file 'ibdata1' must be writable 
2018-06-21T05:42:43.982567Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The innodb_system data file 'ibdata1' must be writable
2018-06-21T05:42:43.982574Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error 
2018-06-21T05:42:44.583494Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2018-06-21T05:42:44.583528Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed. 
2018-06-21T05:42:44.583535Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize builtin plugins. 
2018-06-21T05:42:44.583539Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
2018-06-21T05:42:44.583554Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2018-06-21T05:42:44.583874Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

What are my possibilities?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a problem related to AppArmor. Have you been running this before? Did this distribution of MySQL come from your Linux default package repositories, or did it come directly from Oracle/MySQL? If the former, you'd think they would have made AppArmor policies to allow MySQL to run. If the latter, then that could explain the problem you're seeing.

I see two possibilities for you:

1. Either find and install a suitable AppArmor policy for MySQL to run, and modify it to allow running in what appears to be a non-default datadir (`/data1/database/mysql/`). Or simply create your own policy. The file to edit is apparently `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld`. See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/953988) (Sept. 8, 2017) for more details. See also this comprehensive blog article by Oracle engineer Jeremy Smyth: [AppArmour and MySQL](https://blogs.oracle.com/jsmyth/apparmor-and-mysql) (Jan. 31, 2013). (Thank you, @danblack!)
2. Disable AppArmor. This may not be desirable for security reasons, but if you mostly only ever install packages from your default Linux package repositories then it might be alright. Here are [instructions to disable AppArmor on Debian](https://wiki.debian.org/AppArmor/HowToUse#Disable_AppArmor).

(Disclaimer: I don't have any experience with AppArmor.)

Comment: On option 1; there is [this howto blog from an Oracle engineer](https://blogs.oracle.com/jsmyth/apparmor-and-mysql)